# SIGHUP & SIGCONT

Tags: unix, process, posix, signals

Could you please explain me the logic of UNIX signal system: firstly it sends SIGHUP signal to process group and then it send SIGCONT signal in spite of the main idea of SIGHUP is "kill yourself, there is no terminal anymore"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case the process was stopped with `SIGSTOP` (which, for example, happens when you press CTRL+Z) and can't respond to `SIGHUP` because of that.

Comment: But why so difference? Those who weren't stopped are killed and those who were sleeping are simply made continue?..

Comment: @DimG: No, as soon as they continue, they get that SIGSTOP that was sent earlier. It doesn't get thrown away, it just has to wait.

Comment: Not so,  the signal handler for any given signal is executed regardless of the run state.  the SIGHUP causes the process to *start* exiting, but if suspended, not much actually happens, because the kinds of things that can happen in a signal handler are pretty limited.  SIGCONT resumes the process, and allows any logic that can't happen inside a signal handler to occur.

Comment: @thejh:Interesting. Why not to send at first SIGCONT and then SIGHUP instead of SIGHUP->SIGCONT?

Comment: @DimG: That would produce a race condition. What if you send SIGCONT, another process sends SIGSTOP and then you send GIGHUP? It wouldn't work.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy:I.e. process is anyway directed to exit, but it just stops when it gains processor time. To avoid it, SIGCONT is sent. Am I right?

Comment: Okay, it seems that I understood. Maybe.) Thank you all!)